# Drop voltage from 3.3 V to 2.5 V with step-down dc-dc converter or diode

Tags: led

I'm building a status display for a meeting room. The door to the meeting room gets sunlight from the side, so I will hang the lamp turned 90 degrees and the red status light will point towards the long corridor.

[image: Front]

On Amazon it says for the DC-DC converters I looked at that you need 1.5 V difference between the input voltage (in my case < 3.3 V) and the output voltage (in my case < 2.5 V), which is not the case (0.8 V). Can someone tell me if there is such a thing and how I find it. Alternatively, I would also be grateful if someone recommends a suitable diode (I have no experience with this).

[image: Back]
The (connection of the) solar panel is under the battery. The LEDs are conntected on the left side. They will eat a maximum of 16 mA together with the last DC-DC converter at 2.5 V. Of course at higher voltage they eat more, but that would break ma LOLIN at pin 5 (yellow cable).

I have three DC-DC converters inside (one is inside the D1 mini pro). I didn't want to connect the D1 mini pro with 3.3 V, but connected it with 5 V, so that the internal DC-DC converter doesn't have to be desoldered or reverse floated around and maybe additional modules with 5 V could be connected. In the beginning it worked, i.e. the LEDs were on. After the voltage dropped or something else happened, I now have to replace the last DC-DC converter (I need 2.5 volt but get ~ 2 volt only).

Comment: How much current do you need?

Comment: @Majenko: Less than 16 mA.

Comment: You could use a 2.5V zener diode and a resistor. 1N5222B would do the job. https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_7.html

Comment: I'm going to move this to the EE stack exchange since it's not directly related to Arduno, but general electronics.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: What are you powering at 2.5 V? If you tell us it allows alternative solutions to the problem to be considered. Put the details into your question rather than in the comments. Hit the edit link ...

Comment: After your edit it's still not clear what the 2.5 volt supply is for. The D1 Mini Pro requires a 3.3 volt supply.

Comment: You can. But I think it is wiser to work with 5V, because the lamp doesn't have a Lifepo4 battery with 3.3V and I need a DC-DC converter before the LOLIN anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possible solutions are listed below. They are arranged chronologically according to my trying out. Unfortunately, I have only recently come to the last point or the best idea.

1. Zener diode
2. LDO
3. Transistor
4. Diode
5. Multiple GPIO output pins for higher current

First is not very efficient (tested), i.e. I lose too many mA (my LEDs are too dark).
Second, I have not tested.
Third is as inefficient as first.
Fourthly, it works wonderfully (in combination with fifth). The LOLIN delivers just under 3.3 V, so the voltage drop of 0.69 is acceptable. I get the necessary mA with three output pins connected in parallel. So I could take out the last DC-DC converter and replace it with a simple diode.

[image: Slightly improved version]

By the way: I replaced the battery with a better one. Currently it is at 4.1 Volt. My step-up converter to 5.0 Volt copes with it very well.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to drop 3.3V down to 2.5V for a 16mA load would be a low drop out (LDO) regulator.